# Time lines in cell using %%prun cell magic in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to time a few lines in a jupyter notebook cell and am exploring using the `%%prun` cell magic. However, the output shows mostly functions called by my cell rather than the top-level lines in the cell itself.

For example if I run the following (in a cell):

```
%%prun

x = np.random.rand(10, 10)
y = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)
```

the output is:

```
 5 function calls in 1.353 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    1.353    0.677    1.353    0.677 {method 'rand' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    1.353    1.353 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    1.353    1.353 <string>:3(<module>)
```

This helpfully shows that the rand method is taking most of the time, but it doesn't show that the assignment of the random matrix to y takes almost 6 orders of magnitude more time than the assignment to x. Is there any way to tell which line in the cell is responsible for which calls? Or to simply show the time for each line?